# Vue control and update state from another component with vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

For example, I have a file named App.vue and there I have navigation drawer component. And I have a file named Home.vue with the toolbar component. The thing is that I need to toggle navigation drawer state(true or false) from the Home.vue's  toolbar component(also, the navigation drawer component is rendered in Home.vue). The code below doesn't return any error and doesn't change the navigation drawer visibility. Also, if set state manually in store.js, navigation drawer follows it. Can anyone please help?

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    drawer: false
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleDrawer: function(state) {
      return state.drawer = !state.drawer;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    toggleDrawer({ commit }) {
      commit('toggleDrawer');
    }
  },
  getters: {
    active: (state) => {
      return state.drawer;
    }
  }
})
```

App.vue

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer"> ... </v-navigation-drawer>

<script>
  import store from './store'
    export default {
      data: function() {
        return {
          drawer: this.$store.state.drawer
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<v-toolbar-side-icon @click="$store.commit('toggleDrawer')"> ... </v-toolbar-side-icon>

<script>
  import store from '../store'
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        drawer: this.$store.state.drawer // Seems like I don't need it here
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what does dev tools show ? does the `state.drawer` gets updated when you click the icon ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post, but in case anyone come looking for the answer, this seems to work.

from the Vuex guide, Form Handling section, [Two-way Computed Property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property)

I modified the codesandbox provided by [Sovalina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9541423/sovalina) (thanks!) [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zm714xzyp)

The other way is to use v-model

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app>
```

with the two way computed property, instead of mapGetters

```
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            drawer: {
                get () {
                    return this.$store.state.drawer
                },
                set (value) {
                    this.$store.commit('toggleDrawer', value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigation drawer's property `permanent` instead of v-model (to avoid mutate your store outside vuex) and use the getter `active` you defined.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app >
    <v-navigation-drawer :permanent="active">
      ...
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'active'
      ])
    },
  }
</script>
```

Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="toggle"> ... </v-toolbar-side-icon>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      toggle() {
        this.$store.dispatch('toggleDrawer')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

*Note: as you defined an action `toggleDrawer` in your store you can use dispatch instead of commit.*

Live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jo988kyow)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do as you suggest as soon as I get home!

Comment: Well, thanks, it works, but if I bind value, I need to click twice on the toggle button to make the drawer appear. I checked dev tools and saw that after I close the drawer, the state remains the same(means true) and after I click on button again, it switches to false and on the next click it changes to true. Is there any way to fix this?